# Synology DNS server stops responding queries after a while

Tags: domain-name-system, synology

I have a Synology RT1900ac router with DNS server. It has only one local master forward zone. Really simple one with a few entries, I just followed this [guide](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Application/How_to_set_up_your_domain_with_Synology_DNS_Server). It was working fine until the latest router firmware and DNS Server package update. After a few hours the DNS server stops responding to queries. I need to restart the router and DNS responds again, but only working for a while.
Restarting the package or reinstalling doesn't help, only restart does.

This issue is quite similar to this one: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/875980/synology-dns-stops-responding-after-a-while/937550).

I've opened a ticket at Synology, waiting them to reply.
Do you have any idea how can I debug or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone will have this issue again. I'm just here again to let you know what the Support Engineer said to me.

> "Safe Access in combination with the DNS Server can cause that the DNS Server cannot be used properly anymore."

**Stop Safe Access package** through the Package Center, I hope this will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with build SRM 1.2-7742 Update 2.

Stopping safe access package worked !

Comment: I have that version too (currently the latest release). The devs knows the problem, and will be fixed with an upcoming update for the SRM (no exact release date available).